# How to display index.html present in the war file of a RESTFUL spring project

Tags: spring, rest, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, web.xml

I am new to J2EE/Spring.

I am working on a RESTful Spring service. The controller class has a couple of mappings. There is no web.xml file in my application.

Now, I want to display the index.xml file in the war file which is generated from the build. Is there a way where I can type the url `http://localhost/healthcheck/version`, which will display this static index.html file.

EDIT : I tried using

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/healthcheck")
public class HealthCheck {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/version", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getVersion() throws Exception {
       URL indexUrl = servletContext.getResource("/index.html");
       System.out.println("url path : " + indexUrl.getPath());
       return indexUrl.getPath();
    }
}
```

However, when I type `http://localhost/healthcheck/version`, I get the following DEBUG message in my logs,

```
 10:23:47.199 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /localhost/wcm-service/index.html
    10:23:47.200 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/localhost/wcm-service/index.html]
    10:23:47.200 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/wcm-service/localhost/wcm-service/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'wcm-service'
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information, to start, create a diagram of your project structure (folders, files) and post it here.

Comment: hi @ricksuggs, is it any clearer?

Comment: Repeat: create a diagram of your project structure (folders, files) and post it here. Is your project called wcm-service? If so, at a minimum you'll need to change the URL you are trying to access to http://localhost/wcm-service/healthcheck/version

Comment: Also, by returning indexUrl.getPath(), what value are you expecting that to return? Check the Java documentation to make sure you know what the getPath() method does. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: Read this documentation concerning Spring annotation based controller configuration and make sure your method is returning one of the supported return types, and in the case of String, that a view object exists. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html